# Convert factor to integer in a data frame

Tags: r, integer, dataframe, text-files, r-factor

I have the following code

```
anna.table<-data.frame (anna1,anna2)
write.table<-(anna.table, file="anna.file.txt",sep='\t', quote=FALSE)
```

my table in the end contains numbers such as the following

```
chr         start    end      score
chr2      41237927  41238801    151
chr1      36976262  36977889    226
chr8      83023623  83025129    185
```

and so on......

after that i am trying to to get only the values which fit some criteria such as score less than a specific value

so i am doing the following

```
anna3<-"data/anna/anna.file.txt"
anna.total<-read.table(anna3,header=TRUE)
significant.anna<-subset(anna.total,score <=0.001)

Error: In Ops.factor(score, 0.001) <= not meaningful for factors
```

so i guess the problem is that my table has factors and not integers

I guess that my anna.total$score is a factor and i must make it an integer

If i read correctly the as.numeric might solve my problem

i am reading about the as.numeric function but i cannot understand how i can use it

Hence could you please give me some advices?

thank you in advance

best regards
Anna

PS : i tried the following

```
anna3<-"data/anna/anna.file.txt"
anna.total<-read.table(anna3,header=TRUE)
anna.total$score.new<-as.numeric (as.character(anna.total$score))
write.table(anna.total,file="peak.list.numeric.v3.txt",append = FALSE ,quote = FALSE,col.names =TRUE,row.names=FALSE, sep="\t")

anna.peaks<-subset(anna.total,fdr.new <=0.001)
Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(score, 0.001) : <= not meaningful for factors
```

again i have the same problem......

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `anna.table` (it is a data frame by the way, a table is something else!), the easiest way will be to just do:

```
anna.table2 <- data.matrix(anna.table)
```

as `data.matrix()` will convert factors to their underlying numeric (integer) levels. This will work for a data frame that contains only numeric, integer, factor or other variables that can be coerced to numeric, but any character strings (character) will cause the matrix to become a character matrix.

If you want `anna.table2` to be a data frame, not as matrix, then you can subsequently do:

```
anna.table2 <- data.frame(anna.table2)
```

Other options are to coerce all factor variables to their integer levels. Here is an example of that:

```
## dummy data
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(a = factor(sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE)), 
                  b = runif(10))

## sapply over `dat`, converting factor to numeric
dat2 <- sapply(dat, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) {
                                    as.numeric(x)
                                } else {
                                    x
                                })
dat2 <- data.frame(dat2) ## convert to a data frame
```

Which gives:

```
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 2 3 1 3 3 2 2 1
 $ b: num  0.206 0.177 0.687 0.384 0.77 ...
> str(dat2)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: num  1 2 2 3 1 3 3 2 2 1
 $ b: num  0.206 0.177 0.687 0.384 0.77 ...
```

However, do note that the above will work only if you want the underlying numeric representation. If your factor has essentially numeric levels, then we need to be a bit cleverer in how we convert the factor to a numeric whilst preserving the "numeric" information coded in the levels. Here is an example:

```
## dummy data
set.seed(1)
dat3 <- data.frame(a = factor(sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE), levels = 3:1), 
                   b = runif(10))

## sapply over `dat3`, converting factor to numeric
dat4 <- sapply(dat3, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) {
                                    as.numeric(as.character(x))
                                } else {
                                    x
                                })
dat4 <- data.frame(dat4) ## convert to a data frame
```

Note how we need to do `as.character(x)` first before we do `as.numeric()`. The extra call encodes the level information before we convert that to numeric. To see why this matters, note what `dat3$a` is

```
> dat3$a
 [1] 1 2 2 3 1 3 3 2 2 1
Levels: 3 2 1
```

If we just convert that to numeric, we get the wrong data as R converts the underlying level codes

```
> as.numeric(dat3$a)
 [1] 3 2 2 1 3 1 1 2 2 3
```

If we coerce the factor to a character vector first, then to a numeric one, we preserve the original information not R's internal representation

```
> as.numeric(as.character(dat3$a))
 [1] 1 2 2 3 1 3 3 2 2 1
```

If your data are like this second example, then you can't use the simple `data.matrix()` trick as that is the same as applying `as.numeric()` directly to the factor and as this second example shows, that doesn't preserve the original information.

Comment: @Anna Your edited question is almost the same as before. My Answer includes the use of `as.numeric()`. There is one more gotcha and I'll edit my Answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you very much.....how can i use the as numeric to convert directly the anna.total$score? is the following correct? new.score<-as.numeric (anna.total$score)?

Comment: Depends - see my edited Answer. I don't have `score` or your original data. A lot will depend on what the text file looks like etc and how you are reading it in.

Comment: is it possible from here to send you a part of my file to see how it looks like?

Comment: @Anna Edit your question and include the output from `dput(head(ann.total, n = 10))`. We can then use this to load exactly what you have (well, 10 lines worth) in our R sessions.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an older question, but I just had the same problem and may be it helps:

In this case, your score column seems like it should not have become a factor column. That usually happens after read.table when it is a text column. Depending on which country you are from, may be you separate floats with a "," and not with a ".". Then R thinks that is a character column and makes it a factor. AND in that case Gavins answer won't work, because R won't make "123,456" to 123.456 . You can easily fix that in a text editor with replace "," with "." though.

Comment: Or read the data in with `dec = ","`, which is what that argument is for.