# Converting factor to integer, duplicate

Tags: r, integer

I have a data frame and trying to convert the factor to integer levels for the purpose of assigning different values to integer columns and summing up. The data frame is below

```
SYMBOL             PVALUE1             PVALUE2             PVALUE3
1      <NA>                   0                   0                   0
2      A1BG   0.570568468332992   0.638946096507843   0.500000024038353
3  A1BG-AS1   0.934667427815304   0.535423659692795   0.761546785262885
4      A1CF  0.0547554690106211  0.0774299636523817   0.065332572184696
5       A2M 0.00167287722066533 0.00167287722066533 0.00221961024320294
6   A2M-AS1  0.0029235940742491 0.00167287722066533 0.00167287722066533
7     A2ML1  0.0911572830792113   0.106611564406736  0.0911572830792113
8     A2MP1   0.361053903492157   0.361053903492157   0.266847309723377
9    A4GALT   0.120560747291588  0.0774299636523817  0.0911572830792113
10    A4GNT   0.123873163210698  0.0911572830792113  0.0911572830792113
11     AA06   0.143001729123466   0.106611564406736   0.143001729123466

str(df)
    'data.frame':   21761 obs. of  4 variables:
     $ SYMBOL : chr  NA "A1BG" "A1BG-AS1" "A1CF" ...
     $ PVALUE1: Factor w/ 209 levels "0","0.000109570493049298",..: 1 145 181 74 22 27 84 126 93 94 ...
     $ PVALUE2: Factor w/ 216 levels "0","0.000109570493049298",..: 1 157 147 86 20 20 93 134 86 90 ...
     $ PVALUE3: Factor w/ 207 levels "0","0.000126830713374967",..: 1 140 161 81 25 22 89 118 89 89 ...
```

I try the following code given here : [Convert factor to integer in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480408/convert-factor-to-integer-in-a-data-frame)

```
df1 <- sapply(df, function(x) if(is.factor(df)) {
  as.numeric(as.character(df))
} else {
  df
})
```

But its does not seem to work, give me output like this

```
 SYMBOL          PVALUE1         PVALUE2         PVALUE3        
SYMBOL  Character,21761 Character,21761 Character,21761 Character,21761
PVALUE1 factor,21761    factor,21761    factor,21761    factor,21761   
PVALUE2 factor,21761    factor,21761    factor,21761    factor,21761   
PVALUE3 factor,21761    factor,21761    factor,21761    factor,21761
```

When i try `str(df1)`

```
List of 16
 $ : chr [1:21761] "0" "A1BG" "A1BG-AS1" "A1CF" ...
 $ : Factor w/ 209 levels "0","0.000109570493049298",..: 1 145 181 74 22 27 84 126 93 94 ...
 $ : Factor w/ 216 levels "0","0.000109570493049298",..: 1 157 147 86 20 20 93 134 86 90 ...
 $ : Factor w/ 207 levels "0","0.000126830713374967",..: 1 140 161 81 25 22 89 118 89 89 ...
 $ : chr [1:21761] "0" "A1BG" "A1BG-AS1" "A1CF" ...
 $ : Factor w/ 209 levels "0","0.000109570493049298",..: 1 145 181 74 22 27 84 126 93 94 ...
 $ : Factor w/ 216 levels "0","0.000109570493049298",..: 1 157 147 86 20 20 93 134 86 90 ...
 $ : Factor w/ 207 levels "0","0.000126830713374967",..: 1 140 161 81 25 22 89 118 89 89 ...
 $ : chr [1:21761] "0" "A1BG" "A1BG-AS1" "A1CF" ...
 $ : Factor w/ 209 levels "0","0.000109570493049298",..: 1 145 181 74 22 27 84 126 93 94 ...
 $ : Factor w/ 216 levels "0","0.000109570493049298",..: 1 157 147 86 20 20 93 134 86 90 ...
 $ : Factor w/ 207 levels "0","0.000126830713374967",..: 1 140 161 81 25 22 89 118 89 89 ...
 $ : chr [1:21761] "0" "A1BG" "A1BG-AS1" "A1CF" ...
 $ : Factor w/ 209 levels "0","0.000109570493049298",..: 1 145 181 74 22 27 84 126 93 94 ...
 $ : Factor w/ 216 levels "0","0.000109570493049298",..: 1 157 147 86 20 20 93 134 86 90 ...
 $ : Factor w/ 207 levels "0","0.000126830713374967",..: 1 140 161 81 25 22 89 118 89 89 ...
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 4 4
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "SYMBOL" "PVALUE1" "PVALUE2" "PVALUE3"
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "SYMBOL" "PVALUE1" "PVALUE2" "PVALUE3"
```

Plz let me know what i am missing??

Comment: Typo: use `else {x}` not `else {df}`; similarly `as.character(x)` and `is.factor(x)`

Comment: Oh, really embarrassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
indx <- sapply(df, is.factor)
df[indx] <- lapply(df[indx], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Or a faster option would be

```
df[indx] <- lapply(df[indx], function(x) as.numeric(levels(x))[x])
```